# Application crashed while AWT thread is doing native call to update cursor

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt, native

Our Swing Application crashed while AWT thread is doing native call to update cursor.
We found below same stack trace for almost 5min before application crash

```
"AWT-EventQueue-2" Id=31 in RUNNABLE (running in native)
    at sun.awt.windows.WGlobalCursorManager.setCursor(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.GlobalCursorManager._updateCursor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.GlobalCursorManager.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.GlobalCursorManager$NativeUpdater.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me understand why AWT thread keep on printing the same stack trace and what it is trying to do?

We are using JDK 6
windows pc
Issue resolved after application restart and is not reproducible.

Comment: What is your jdk version?

Comment: we are using Java6. Application works fine after restart and is not reproducible.